# -bash: auto: command not found

Tags: debian, networking, command-line

I'm going to config my network interfaces and run this command:
`auto eth0`
but it returns `-bash: auto: command not found`. It seems I've missed something which I don't know. Any idea? What should I install?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`auto eth0` is [`interfaces(5)`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=interfaces&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en) syntax. It's a line you would add to `/etc/network/interfaces`, not a command to be run in a shell. Once you correctly configure the interface in `/etc/network/interfaces`, you can run the `ifup`/`ifdown` commands to apply them.